# FBWebDialogs does not show - no reaction

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook-sdk-3.1

Please if any of you could help me with this Facebook SDK. I don't know what's going on, and the problem is that when button with facebook is clicked nothing shows up - FBWebDialog is dead but "Memory managment/consumption bar in Xcode when app is fired allocs additional memory (about 22 MB) after that action. I have followed official tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share and reainstalled facebook SDK, added things like AppID etc. Even that haven't helped me. What's wrong with that?

I'm using iphone simulator and ios 8 and Xcode 6.0. About 2 mounths ago everything worked fine. Pop-up window was showed in application until now.
Any help with this will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

MY CODE:

```
[FBLoginView class];

            FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
            params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/"];

            // If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
            if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
                // Present the share dialog
                [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                  if(error) {
                                                      // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                      // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                      NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                                  } else {
                                                      // Success
                                                      NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                                  }
                                              }];
            } else {
                // Present the feed dialog
                // Put together the dialog parameters
                NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                                               @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                               @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                                               @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                                               nil];

                // Show the feed dialog
                [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                       parameters:params
                                                          handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                              if (error) {
                                                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                                  NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                                              } else {
                                                                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                                      // User cancelled.
                                                                      NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                                  } else {
                                                                      // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                                      NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                                      if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                                          // User cancelled.
                                                                          NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                                      } else {
                                                                          // User clicked the Share button
                                                                          NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                                          NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              }
                                                          }];
            }
```

Standard code from Facebook site but still no reaction.

Comment: I need to see your FBWebDialog code in order to help with this.  You should always include relevant code when asking for help.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see which way its going (share dialog or feed dialog?).  Have you tried running this on a device with facebook app installed?  Have you set breakpoints in the handlers to see if they are getting called?

Comment: I run it on simulator. In another project it runs ok. It get to the else condition but do nothing there. Memory is allocated but nothing more happens.